# Send values to setTimeout no works

Tags: jquery, hide, settimeout

I create function with setTimeout into for stop working in a time and inside function i have 2 divs for hide with a time , the problem it´s with the var time_hide that indicate the time for hide divs , into setTimeout no works or impossible read this var

The script :

```
<script>

function show(timer,timer_hide)
{

setTimeout(function() 
{

$("#alert_background").hide(timer_hide);
$("#alert_window").hide(timer_hide);

}, timer);


}

show(4000,3000);

</script>
```

The divs must close in 3 seconds but in this case no works and close very fast as if no exist the time or the value of var timer_hide

Thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: your code should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

You could use instead `delay()`:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PunLW/)

```
function show(timer, timer_hide) {
     $("#alert_background").delay(timer).hide(timer_hide);
    $("#alert_window").delay(timer).hide(timer_hide);
}
```